# How to put points in a graph ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this 2 DataFrames

```
Data_UK7

     Fecha    cases   TotalCases

1   2020-03-29  2546    17089   
2   2020-03-30  2433    19522   
3   2020-03-31  2619    22141   
4   2020-04-01  3009    25150   
5   2020-04-02  4324    29474   
6   2020-04-03  4244    33718   
7   2020-04-04  4450    38168   
8   2020-04-05  3735    41903
```

And this

```
Predict

   Fecha       n   TotalCases
2020-04-05  0 days  41903       
2020-04-06  1 days  46734       
2020-04-07  2 days  52122       
2020-04-08  3 days  58131       
2020-04-09  4 days  64833       
2020-04-10  5 days  72308
```

After this I make the next plot

```
ggplot(data=Predict, aes(x=Fecha, y=TotalCases)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=TotalCases),linetype = "twodash",color="Red")+
  geom_point(color="blue")+
  geom_line(data=Data_UK7,linetype = "twodash")+
  geom_point(color="blue")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks ="1 day")
```

And I have this output

[image]

How can I make the dots look throughout the graph as in the second part of the graph and prevent the dates from being duplicated at the bottom ?

Comment: for your second `geom_point()` call, add `data=Data_UK7` otherwise it inherits the dataframe specified in the `ggplot()` call

Comment: And for the date issue, your dates are `character` or `factor` class. Make them `Date` class with `as.Date()`.